# How to set up a reverse connection proxy server?

Tags: windows, reverse-proxy

My situation looks like this: I want to browse websites on my local Windows computer with IP from my other Windows computer that is behind NAT and I can't port forward there. I don't really want to install any big programs on the gateway computer because it is very slow. A program that I can just double click (or run through cmd) to tunnel http/https data from my local computer in the background would be the best. I was thinking about writing a program to do this, but there must be an easier solution. I have made some research about this, but didn't really find anything for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

-use rinetd (http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/). it will listen to the ip:port and forward to the dst:port. it's very small program.

Comment: from what I've understand I have to use it on my gateway server with configuration like this:
0.0.0.0 80 my.lo.cal.ip 1001
How do I make my local browser connect through gateway though? Just reminding, the gateway server is behind a NAT.

Comment: 1. client => gateway:port (rinetd) => your.pc:port (is it your diagram ?). 2. client => gateway:port (rinetd) => another.pc:port (rinetd) => your.pc:port